# Cannot import name 'easter' from 'holidays'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import `fbprophet` on Python Anaconda, however, I get this error:

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'easter' from 'holidays'
```

Can anyone suggest what might have gone wrong?

Code:

```
from fbprophet import fbprophet
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm using anaconda, and the only solution that worked for me was:

Replace **line 16** in **fbprophet/hdays.py** (\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\fbprophet\hdays.py):

```
from holidays import WEEKEND, HolidayBase, easter, rd
```

to

```
from holidays import WEEKEND, HolidayBase
from dateutil.easter import easter
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta as rd
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a recent known error that has been reported. ([look here for the thread](https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays/issues/277)).

The reason and outline is -

> "easter" is not a holidays function, but instead a dateutil library function.
>   Until the previous version of holidays (0.9.12) it was "accidentally" accessible, due to it being imported in holidays.py (main library module, now removed in favour of single country modules), but its direct reference made in prophet is basically wrong (same goes for WEEKEND, HolidayBase etc., not meant for being accessed from outside holidays library).
>   In order to fix fbprophet, replacing the erroring import with
>
> > from dateutil.easter import easter

Comment: okay this imported easter for me but having same error when importing fbprophet.

Comment: @ALAUKIKHARSH did you edit the `fbprophet/hdays.py` file ?? or did you just add `from dateutil.easter import easter` to your existing code ?

Comment: @ALAUKIKHARSH also a fixed version exists its just not on PIPY yet, but you can clone it from github. You could use that as well

Comment: Thanks problem solved. it was a typo error in hdays.py this time

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem, googled and solved it.
For solution, do the followings;

1. Open `python3.6/site-packages/fbprophet/hdays.py` file.
2. Replace

   `from holidays import WEEKEND, HolidayBase, easter, rd`

to

```
    from holidays import WEEKEND, HolidayBase
    from dateutil.easter import easter
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta as rd
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a popular issue people have been facing recently. Check out https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays/issues/277#issuecomment-578562797. For your solution, do

```
from dateutil.easter import easter
```

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: okay this imported easter for me but having same error when importing fbprophet.

Comment: pip uninstall cython --> repeatedly until your system is clear

then
pip install cython

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Error is mainly coming in line 'from holidays import WEEKEND, HolidayBase, easter, rd ' from file 'fbprophet/hdays.py'

I have tried below temporary solution-

1.download 'hdays.py' from https://github.com/facebook/prophet/tree/master/python/fbprophet (fixed and released on github by fbprophet maintainers)

2.replace already present 'hdays.py' in your local system path -\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\fbprophet 
with downloaded 'hdays.py'

if above will not work then install package 
-pip install lunarcalendar